# Mocking a Snowflake Connection Isn't Working When Calling the Function

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

Say I have a file `utils/snowflake_manager.py` that takes in table metadata, calls snowflake to get more metadata about those tables and returns all that information in some organized way (maybe a list of dictionaries)...

```
# utils/snowflake_manager.py

import snowflake.connector

class SnowflakeManager:
    def__init__(self):
        self.conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user="user", .... , warehouse="warehouse")

    def get_table_type(self, table_name):
        query = f"""SELECT ... .. WHERE table_name = '{table_name}'"""

        table_or_view = self.conn.cursor().execute(query).fetchone()[0] # This should return 'VIEW' or 'TABLE'

        return table_or_view

    def format_some_input_data(self, input):
        table_name = ... some transformation logic on input arg
        table_type = self.get_table_type(table_name)

        final = ... some more transformation logic that uses the table_type value

        return final

if __name__ == "__main__":
  snowflake_manager = SnowflakeManager()
```

I want to test the `format_some_input_data` method without making a call to Snowflake. It makes sense to mock the `get_table_type` function and have that return `VIEW` for the test case.

Here's my `tests/test_snowflake_manager.py` file...

```
from utils import SnowflakeManager # I have an __init__ file in the utils dir/package that exports the SnowflakeManager object directly

import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("utils.snowflake_manager")
def test_get_table_type(mock_get_table_type):
    input_dummy_data = [...{"table": "someTableThatDoesntExistInSnowflake"}...]

    expected = [...{"table": "someTableThatDoesntExistInSnowflake", "table_type": "VIEW"},...]

    mock_get_table_type.get_table_type.return_value = "VIEW"
    
    assert SnowflakeManager().format_some_input_data(input_dummy_data) == expected
```

PyTest keeps failing because it is running the `format_some_input_data` function, which runs the `get_table_type` against the real Snowflake database with table = someTableThatDoesntExistInSnowflake. Since this table doesn't exist, I get a `None` value for the `table_type`

I expected that calling `SnowflakeManager().format_some_input_data(input_dummy_data)` would then call the mocked `get_table_type` function and return `"VIEW"` instead of connecting to my actual Snowflake DB.

Can someone help clarify where I am going wrong?